# Allow user to choose language of a postal form and adapt the select options accordingly in jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, dynamic, html-select

I have to create a form that prompts the user to enter their Zip code, State and Street address. But first, the user should be able to choose their language in a `<select>`, and the labels and select options (such as their title) have to be set in the language they choose.

After the language, they should be able to select their country in a short list, and the regex validation for the Zip codes would of course have to match the selected country.

I'd like to do it without a plugin.
What would be the cleanest way to do it?

What I've thought of thus far:

```
//Get the selected language and country
function which(){
    lang = $('#language').prop('selectedIndex');
    country = $('#country').prop('selectedIndex');
    if(lang == 1){
        pickedLang = "en";
    }else if(lang == 2){
        pickedLang = "de";
    }else if(lang == 3){
        pickedLang = "fr";
    }

    if(country == 1){
        pickedCountry = "US";
    }else if(country == 2){
        pickedCountry = "UK";
    }else if(country == 3){
        pickedCountry = "DE";
    }else if(country == 4){
        pickedCountry = "FR";
    }else{
        pickedCountry = 0;
    }
}
```

And then, to change the labels and options to match the selected language:

```
$('#language').change(function(){
    if(pickedLang == "en"){
        $('.country label').text('Country');
        $('.language label').text('Language');
        $('#country option').eq(0).text('Pick a country');
        $('#country option').eq(1).text('United States');
        $('#country option').eq(2).text('United Kingdom');
        $('#country option').eq(3).text('Germany');
        $('#country option').eq(4).text('France');

        $('.gender label').text('Title');
        $('#gender option').eq(0).text('Choose...');
        $('#gender option').eq(1).text('Mr.');
        $('#gender option').eq(2).text('Ms.');
        $('#gender option').eq(3).text('Miss');

        $('.name label').text('Name:');
        $('.first-name label').text('First name:');
        $('.street label').text('Street:');
        $('.number label').text('Number:');
        if(pickedCountry == "UK"){
            $('.postcode label').text('Post Code:');
        }else{
            $('.postcode label').text('Zip Code:');
        }
        $('.state label').text('State:');
        $('.city label').text('City:');
    }else if [...]
```

But I really feel like this could be simplified and cleaner somehow.

**Edit:
Thanks to Nicklas, I've now cleaned up the code and decided to use JSON to store all the labels in the different languages.**

```
{
"en": [
{
    "languageLabel":    "Language",
    "countryLabel":     "Country",
    "nameLabel":        "Name",
    "emailLabel":       "E-mail",
    "streetLabel":      "Street",
    "nbrLabel":         "N°",
    "zipLabel":         "Zip",
    "stateLabel":       "State",
    "cityLabel":        "City",
    "sendLabel":        "Send"  
}
],

"fr": [
{
    "languageLabel":    "Langue",
    "countryLabel":     "Pays",
    "nameLabel":        "Nom",
    "emailLabel":       "Adresse e-mail",
    "streetLabel":      "Rue",
    "nbrLabel":         "N°",
    "zipLabel":         "CP",
    "stateLabel":       "Province",
    "cityLabel":        "Ville",
    "sendLabel":        "Envoyer"   
}
],

"de": [
{
    "languageLabel":    "Sprache",
    "countryLabel":     "Land",
    "nameLabel":        "Name",
    "emailLabel":       "E-Mail-Adresse",
    "streetLabel":      "Straße",
    "nbrLabel":         "N°",
    "zipLabel":         "PLZ",
    "stateLabel":       "Staat",
    "cityLabel":        "Stadt",
    "sendLabel":        "Senden"    
}
]
}
```

jQuery:

```
var labels;
    $.getJSON("path-to-json-file",function(data){
            labels=data;
    }); 


    ////////// DETECT CHANGES IN THE SELECTBOXES
    $('#language, #country').change(function(){
        which();
        var currentLabels = labels[pickedLanguage];
        $('#language-container label').text(currentLabels.languageLabel);
        $('#country-container label').text(currentLabels.countryLabel);
    });
```

However, the console returns an error and says it cannot read the property 'fr' (or any other language) of undefined. As I'm not familiar with the use of JSON at all, I'm afraid I messed up somewhere.

Comment: Also, make sure that the ajax request has really finished before you're trying to access `labels`. If the request is not finished, then  `labels` will of course not contain anything.

Comment: And skip the square brackets (array declarators) inside the JSON object. The way you have it now, you'll have to reference `currentLabels[0].languageLabel` and so forth.

Comment: This is pretty cool. If you've fleshed out your JSON table with additional countries, would you be willing to share it so I (and other users) don't have to recreate it from scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try cleaning this up by making a dict of all the variables:

```
var langOptions = {
    en: {
        countryLabel:  'Country',
        languageLabel: 'Language',

        ...
    }
}
```

Then when you need to access the appropriate ones:

```
var myOptions = langOptions[pickedLang];
```

Then you can access them in the same way always, without endless if statements:

```
$('.country label').text(myOptions.countryLabel);
$('.language label').text(myOptions.languageLabel);
```

Further on, consider stashing away the `langOptions` object in json format and loading it through ajax using `jQuery.getJSON()`. That should make for much, much cleaner code.

**EDIT: An example of usage, to clarify:** http://jsfiddle.net/9Npg2/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! You definitely sent me on the right track. I've never used JSON, so I decided to give it a shot to learn how it works. But I'm afraid I got something wrong (see edit of the original post).

Comment: Here's an example of how it's used: http://jsfiddle.net/9Npg2/. Hope that clears it all up!

Comment: I checked that and it seems correct. However, I think what's wrong is that the script fails to store the JSON data into the labels variable, therefore it says it's undefined. Is the bit where I try to store the JSON in the variable correct?

Comment: Yeah, I just commented your question with the probable issue. `$.getJSON` is an asynchronous request, so any calls to the `label` variable should not be made before the request has loaded. Consider declaring the `change` listener inside the `getJSON` callback.